# Question about impurity scattering of multiband Hamiltonians in $T$-matrix approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

Imagine, we have a 2-by-2 Hamiltonian:
$$
H = H_0+H_{imp}.
$$
The impurity Hamiltonian $H_{imp}$ is
$$H_{imp}=u_{imp}I_2\sum_{r_{imp}}\delta(\vec r - \vec r_{imp}).$$
$I_2$ is identity matrix of order 2, $u_{imp}$ is strength of impurities (for example, Eq. 10 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0210.pdf)). The self-energy for retarded Green's function $G^R$ of this type of impurity potentials is given by T-matrix approximation as $\Sigma^R = n_{imp}T^R$ with (see Eq. 25-26 of above mentioned article)
$$
T^R = u_{imp} \left(1-\int d^d\vec k \; G^R \; u_{imp}\right)^{-1}
$$

I am confused that if here it is a scalar "1" or $I_2$? I believe that it is $I_2$ because the other term here ($\int d^d\vec k \; G^R \; u_{imp}$) is also a 2-by-2 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian is not 2-by-2, but in a product space - likely Eucledean 3D space and discrete spin_up/down space, e.g.:
$$H_0=I_2\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m} + \Delta\sigma_z.$$

The if the impurity is non-magnetic, its Hamiltonian is a unity matrix in spin space, i.e.,
$$
I_2 =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Simply replacing it by $1$ (a scalar rather than & unity matrix) is a common shorthand, but is mathematically sloppy.

**Remark:**
If the Hamiltonian is indeed a multiband Hamiltonian, then it is in a space of the Bloch functions, which have both discrete band index and continuous $\mathbf{k}$ component. In case of two bands and effective mass approximation it is similar to the spin case discussed above, bit assuming that the impurity Hamilronian is diagonal in the band index is then an approximation.